# Primefaces crop converter error

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using the following code and try to crop an image which takes its value from a bean :

```
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:row>
                <p:column>
                    <p:imageCropper id="imageCropperId" value="#{imageCropperBean.croppedImage}"
                        image="#{imageCropperBean.newImageName}">
                    </p:imageCropper>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>Bild innerhalb des Rahmens positionieren</p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <p:graphicImage id="localCroppedImage" value="#{imageCropperBean.newImageName}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
            <p:row>
                <p:column colspan="3">
                    <p:commandButton value="Crop" actionListener="#{imageCropperBean.crop}"
                        update=":growl imageCropperId localCroppedImage" />
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
        </p:panelGrid>
```

I am always getting the error : **{0}: Conversion error occurred.** inside growl, due to :

```
value="#{imageCropperBean.croppedImage}"
```

The converter attribute from declaration says :

> An el expression or a literal text that defines a converter for the
>   component. When it's an EL expression,   it's resolved to a converter
>   instance. In case it's a static text, it must refer to a converter id.

but the EL expression is evaluated at String. What should I do? It works if I put a normal String pointing to an existing image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix this error.

For the ones which will have the same problem, basically this occurs when

- Either errors are being thrown during cropping phase (e.g. files not found or if the *cropped image is not relative to the original one*)
- Either the value which is evaluated from EL  `image="#{imageCropperBean.newImageName}"` is evaluated to null, while trying to skip the cropping (I couldn't suceed with required="true" so I used rendering="someCondition")